# How to mock a field which is created by constructor within a constructor

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Considering following design, `Parent` has a field of `Child` instance, which is initiated in Parent's constructor, by its own constructor. Then to unit test the `thanksGivingVisit()` method from Parent class, I need to mock the child object, However I am facing challenge to implement it by Mockito.

I go over a few online resources regarding using `MockedConstruction`, I think I can mock the `child` object with it but still not sure how to inject it to `Parent` class

BTW, I am using Mockito 4.5 and can't replace it with PowerMock or other framework.

```
public class Parent{

    private Child child;

    public Parent(Legacy legacy, Config config){
        child = new Child(legacy, config.getBirthCertificate());
    }

    public Result thanksGivingVisit(){
        
        // let's mock the result to avoid DB transaction in the `withdraw` method
        // however, how to mock child object?
        Int amount = child.withDrawFromBackAccount();
        
        // use amount to calculate Result object...
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a `ChildFactory` class which has a singleton instance which you pass to the `Parent` constructor. Create a mock `ChildFactory` which created mocked `Child` objects.

Comment: @tgdavies thanks! Does it mean the Parent-Child implementation need to change just to fit the unit test framework?

Comment: Yes, to make code easily testable with mocks you want to avoid calling `new` directly.

Comment: You might want to read up on the topic of dependency injection.

Comment: @Gene DI through Spring Framework like bean ?

Comment: What is `withdraw` mentioned in the comment? Do you need to swap `Child` with a test double or could you only replace the DB with a test double and still use the real `Child`? How does `Child` access the DB?